# When downloading a repository from github, how do I know which are the relevant files and which are github stuff, that I can delete?

Tags: github

I downloaded this [template](https://github.com/ColorlibHQ/AdminLTE/releases/tag/v3.2.0) and I wonder which are the files that are mandatory for the template to work and which can be deleted?

Comment: In general: By learning the basics of the technologies you are using and not just pulling in large collections of code you don't understand.

Answer (score -1):

Delete everything that has "git" in the name I think.

Comment: So `README.md` is mandatory for the template to work?

Comment: Oh you're right. Probably not.. What does .md stand for, why is it not just ".txt"? And what would be a better answer?

Comment: Markdown. Because it isn't plain text. The question is not suitable for SO and shouldn't be answered.

Comment: Ah okay, sorry, I thought I could help OP but I made it worse apparently.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).